# Spring boot gradle flyway - validate error - Schema-validation: missing table

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, flyway

I am getting the below error
**Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [my.table]**

Is this any version issue? Most examples don't use schema even the official?
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/main/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-flyway

Database: MariaDB

Steps:
Created V1__init.sql using

#spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
#spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=V1__init.sql
#spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-source=metadata

Then added flyway plugin

flyway.properties at same level as build.gradle

> flyway.user=py1***
>
> flyway.password=ENC(aCUoPgiA+ZyHDFdrEXa)
>
> flyway.schemas=my
>
> flyway.createSchemas=false
>
> flyway.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/my
>
> flyway.locations=filesystem:db/migration

application.props

> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=my

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

moved V1__init.sql to db\migrations

My entities don't specify schema

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints={
        @UniqueConstraint(....})
    }) 
public class SomeTable {...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added dependency - implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
and it was resolved

(next error about json type column - found [longtext (Types#LONGVARCHAR)], but expecting [json (Types#VARCHAR)]  which isn't in the scope of this post)